# How to combine ExpectedConditions class with an implemented class in a webDriver test

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, conditional-statements, implements

I have different classes that implements ExpectedCondition; one of them, AttributeContainsCondition, is showing below. On my tests, I am trying to use something like condition dot and see all methods available from ExpectedCondition and all classes I have created that implements ExpectedCondition.

So on my tests I am trying to add something to pick up all the methods from ExpectedCondition and all the classes I created that implements ExpectedCondition. I am importing the location where I have created the classes.

```
public class AttributeContainsCondition implements ExpectedCondition<Boolean>{

    private final WebElement element;
    private final String attributeName, expectedValue;

    public AttributeContainsCondition(WebElement element, String attributeName, String expectedValue){
        this.element = element;
        this.attributeName = attributeName;
        this.expectedValue = expectedValue;
    }

    public Boolean apply(WebDriver input){
        return StringUtils.contains(element.getAttribute(attributeName), expectedValue);
    }
}
```

test file: this is not working

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
public class VerifyInfoTest extends mainTest {
    ExpectedConditions condition = new ExpectedConditions<boolean>(); ????
```

so if I use condition.xxxx I should see the methods from ExpectedConditions and
all the classes I created that implements it

Thank you :)

Comment: Why do you initialize your condition as such? This should be `ExpectedCondition<Boolean> cond = new AttributeContainsCondition(...);`

Comment: Thanks..I am seeing this error: "Syntax error on token "boolean", Dimensions expected after this token". And also, since I have about 15 classes like AttributeContainsCondition, I was trying to get away from initialize every single one of them if possible.

Comment: `Boolean`, not `boolean`! `Boolean` is the object, `boolean` is the primitive type

Comment: I get this new error: The type ExpectedConditions is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Boolean>

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use your AttributeContainsCondition say in a `wait.until`

you can use it the following way:

```
boolean result = wait.until(new AttributeContainsCondition(
      yourWebElement,
      "yourAttributeName",
      "yourExpectedValue"));
```